# How to make a Tile/Grid layout like Gridster.js in AS3?

Tags: javascript, layout, actionscript, flex4, gridster

I want to make a custom layout which behaves like this shown in picture below.

I have already tried Tile Layout and to modify its  calculateDropIndex method but not get desired behavior.

Tile layout works well when all the tiles are of same height and width but in my case tile size are different.

http://gridster.net/

[image]
[Gridster layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Jpq.png)

Comment: I do not know your end goals for the movable panels, but if you are looking to build a dashboard style application, Quite a while ago, I used the Adobe open-source Flex 3/4 Dashboard (developed by WASI) (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/dashboard.html) and then they had a 4-part series that ported it to Flex4 (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/migrating-flex-apps-part4.html). I ended up writing a custom layout to handle 'pods' that differed in size (just like Gridster). If I'd had to do it again I would just buy Flexicious's Dashboard http://www.flexicious.com/Home/Dashboard

Comment: @RobertN thanks for the reply. i have checked this dashboard example from the links you provide but here  tiles(pods) are re-sizing as number of pods increases. My requirement is to increase height of the pod container as number of widgets increases.As you said you have write custom layout which handles different pod size can i have a demo link for that or the custom layout file itself.

Comment: That was a contract project so I can not redistribute that but most if it was based on the Flex 4 Spark Layout Class, just extended TileLayout...

Comment: OK. no problem but is it possible to achieve same behavior as gridster by extending Tile layout?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a little bit more try i am able make a gridster like drag n drop gird component.

here is a brief summery of how i have made this component.
while adding pods in to container add one more pod at the same position and keep it's visibility off. this extra node will be our drop indicator.
keep all the original nodes in one array say nodes, and all extra nodes in another array say dropIndicators.

for example if add nodes A, B and C in the container. we will add three extra nodes X, Y and Z respectively one for each main node.

and over nodes array will be

```
node[0] = A;
node[1] = B;
node[2] = C;
```

and dropIndicators array will be

```
dropIndicators[0] = X;
dropIndicators[1] = Y;
dropIndicators[2] = Z;
```

now you will need following function to update nodes position when we drag any node.

1. CalculateDropLocation -  to calculate new drop location while dragging.
2. CheckCollision -  to check collision between two nodes.
3. FixCollision - if there is a collision we will fix the collision using this function. this function will mode all the colliding nodes downwards recursively.
4. updateNodes - once the collision is fixed we will update all the nodes using this function. this function will move node upward if there is an empty space.

now when we start dragging A node calculate new drop location for A node and move it's relative extra node i.e. X to the new drop location, check if X is colliding with any other extra node. we will use the dropIndicators array in all the functions.
if collistion than call fixCollision() function, than call update node function.

and at the end once all the nodes are updated set the position of all the extra nodes to it's original nodes i.e. set X's position to A's position , Y's position to B and so on. while updating original nodes position you can use Move animation to move nodes smoothly in the container.

hope this will help. using this method you can make this type of layout in any language.

hope this will help.

for more details and sample application with source visit this [link](http://usefulflexcomponents.blogspot.in/2015/12/blog-post.html)

http://usefulflexcomponents.blogspot.in/2015/12/blog-post.html